# Can't use GetStaticProp in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am following a tutorial online that uses the older version of Next.js. I am now using Next.js 13, and tried to implement GetStaticProp() to fetch data from my api, but cannot use that function under the app folder.

I am now trying to implement the data fetching as Next.js suggests to do it (https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching). The error that I am getting is:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')

My code is:

```
import Layout from "components/Layout.js";
import ResourceHighlight from "components/ResourceHighlight.js";
import ResourceList from "components/ResourceList.js";
import Newsletter from "components/Newsletter.js";
import Footer from "components/Footer.js";


function Home({resources}) {
  return ( 
    <Layout> 
     <ResourceHighlight
        resources={resources.slice(0,2)}
      />
      <ResourceList
        resources={resources.slice(2)}
      />
       <Newsletter /> 
      <Footer />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export async function getData(){ 
  const resData = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/resources"'); 
  const data = await resData.json(); 

  //return resData.json(); 

  return { 
    props: { 
      resources: data
    }
  }
}


// export async function getStaticProps() {

//   const resData = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/resources");
//   const data = await resData.json();

//   return {
//     props: {
//       resources: data
//     }
//   }
// }



export default Home;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I tried to implement the new function with guidance from the next.js documentation but something is not working.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate even though it is top of Google when looking for help with using GetStaticProp in Next.js 13

Wrote up an answer to help rookies like me here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76766776/1296746

Answer (score 6):

In `next.js 13`, `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, and `getInitialProps` are not supported in server components which uses `app` directory as stated in next js beta docs that you linked.
Reason of error you are getting is that `resources` is undefined. Please check resources value.

Answer (score 4):

actually `getStaticProps` is not supported in `next.js 13` instead you should use `generateStaticParams`. ref [the github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50424)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe NextJS vs 13.4 does not support `getStaticProps`
but you can't use same as:

This request should be cached until manually invalidated.
Similar to `getStaticProps`.
`force-cache` is the default and can be omitted.
`fetch(URL, { cache: 'force-cache' });`

This request should be refetched on every request.
Similar to `getServerSideProps`.
`fetch(URL, { cache: 'no-store' });`

This request should be cached with a lifetime of 10 seconds.
Similar to `getStaticProps` with the `revalidate` option.
`fetch(URL, { next: { revalidate: 10 } });`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can still use [Pages Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages), if you would like to use `getStaticProps` and related functionalities. For new applications, Next.js recommends using the App Router and existing applications can incrementally migrate to the App Router.
It's unclear why you have used `slice` method for **resources** `JSON` object since it's intended for an `Array`.
If you're using the App Router, this kind of approach can be used here:

```
import Layout from "components/Layout.js";
import ResourceHighlight from "components/ResourceHighlight.js";
import ResourceList from "components/ResourceList.js";
import Newsletter from "components/Newsletter.js";
import Footer from "components/Footer.js";

async function getResources() {
  const res = await fetch('https://example.com/api/resources');
  // Handle errors
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
  const resources = await getResources();
  const resourcesArray = Object.values(resources);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ResourceHighlight resources={resourcesArray.slice(0, 1)} />
      <ResourceList resources={resourcesArray.slice(1)} />
      <Newsletter />
      <Footer />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

As @Nam mentioned, if you want to [dynamically fetch the data](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#dynamic-data-fetching) (fresh data on every fetch request), use the `cache: 'no-store'` option.

More information about Data Fetching:

- [Using App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching)
- [Using Pages Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting that error because getStaticProps is not returning any thing. Resources values is null in props.

This code will work without error

```
function Home({resources}) {
  return ( 
    <Layout> 
     <ResourceHighlight
        resources={resources?.slice(0,2)}
      />
     
   )}
```