# getStaticProps is not allowed in the app directory when attempting to fetch data

Tags: next.js

How can I re-render data when using the latest app routing in Next.js? I'm encountering an error stating that getStaticProps is not allowed in the app directory when attempting to fetch data.

```
'use client'
import Breadcrumb from "../../components/layout/breadcrumb";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faHeart } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import TabSection from "../../components/productpage/Tab";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter, useSearchParams ,usePathname} from "next/navigation";
import { fetchObjectFromProducts } from "@/app/utils/dataApi";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function ProductsDescriptionPage({params}) {
 const router = useRouter();
  // const  productSlug  = useSearchParams(); 
  const pathname = usePathname();
const {productSlug} = params
console.log("productSlug:",productSlug)
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const unslugifiedProductName = unslugify(productSlug);
        const response = await fetchObjectFromProducts(unslugifiedProductName);
        setProduct(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    if (productSlug) {
      fetchProduct();
    }
  }, [productSlug]);

  function unslugify(slug) {
    // Replace hyphens with spaces and capitalize the first letter of each word
    const words = slug.split('-');
    const unslugified = words
      .map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
      .join(' ');

    return unslugified;
  }
return (
    <main className="container mx-auto p-4  md:px-10 md:pr-10 mt-16 ">
      <Breadcrumb />
{product && (
        <div>
          <h2>{product.name}</h2>
          <p>{product.short_description}</p>
          {/* Display other product details */}
        </div>
      )}
<section className="sm:ml-10 se:ml-10 md:ml-0 ss:ml-20">
      <div className="text-gray-700 body-font mt-7">
        <div className="container sm:mx-auto flex sm:px-2 sm:py-2 md:flex-row sm:-ml-12 md:ml-0  flex-col sm:items-center">
          <div className="lg:flex-grow md:w-1/2 lg:pr-24 md:pr-16 flex flex-col md:items-start md:text-left md:mb-0 items-center text-center">
            <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row items-start sm:items-center">
              <Image
                src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000/fff.jpg"
                width={200} height={150}
                alt="..."
                className="mr-8"
              />
              <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-col mt-7 ">
<div className="flex-shrink-0">
                <h2 className="page-headings text-left mb-2 whitespace-nowrap">
                  Featured products
                </h2>
</div>
                <p className="card-text para leading-tight">
                  Your one stop customer support platform
                </p>
                <div className="card--stats md:mr-0 sm:mr-60 se:mr-60 ">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className="items-start  mx-8" />
                  
                  <span className="gray mr-2">37</span>
                  <span className="gray">Reviews</span>
                </div>

                <div
                  className="text-left flex items-center sm:items-end my-3 "
                  role="group"
                  aria-label="Tools"
                >
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="  bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-300 rounded-full font-medium px-3  md:mr-2 mb-2 w-auto h-6 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:border-gray-900 dark:focus:ring-gray-700"
                    style={{ lineHeight: "0.8" }}
                  >
                    Blogging
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-300 rounded-full font-medium px-3 mr-2 mb-2 w-auto h-6 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:border-gray-900 dark:focus:ring-gray-700"
                    style={{ lineHeight: "0.8" }}
                  >
                    Blogging
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-300 rounded-full font-medium px-3 mr-2 mb-2 w-auto h-6 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:border-gray-900 dark:focus:ring-gray-700"
                    style={{ lineHeight: "0.8" }}
                  >
                    All
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* <div className="flex justify-center">
              <button className="inline-flex text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg">Button</button>
              <button className="ml-4 inline-flex text-gray-700 bg-gray-200 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-300 rounded text-lg">Button</button>
            </div> */}
          </div>

          <div className="lg:max-w-lg lg:w-full xs:-ml-16 sm:ml-0    ss:mr-16 md:w-1/2 w-5/6">
            <div className="flex justify-center  md:justify-end mt-4 sm:hidden  sm:items-start sm:justify-start md:mr-0   ">
              {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className="text-2xl mr-3" /> */}
              <button
                type="button"
                className="flex-shrink-0 h-10 border border-purple-800 bg-white bg-opacity-0 hover:bg-opacity-10 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-purple-300 font-medium text-gray-800 text-sm px-6 py-2 text-center dark:bg-purple-300 dark:hover:bg-purple-600 dark:focus:bg-purple-900 mr-3"
              >
                View more
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="flex-shrink-0 h-10 bg-purple-800 hover:bg-purple-900 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-purple-300 font-medium  text-white text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center  dark:bg-purple-300 dark:hover:bg-purple-600 dark:focus:bg-purple-900"
              >
                Go to Website
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="hidden sm:flex md:justify-end mt-4 md:items-end ">
              <div className="flex">
                {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className="text-2xl mr-14 " /> */}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="max-w-4xl border border-purple-800 bg-white bg-opacity-0 hover:bg-opacity-10 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-purple-300 font-medium text-gray-800 text-sm px-6 py-2 text-center dark:bg-purple-300 dark:hover:bg-purple-600 dark:focus:bg-purple-900 mr-3"
                >
                  View more
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="bg-purple-800 hover:bg-purple-900focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-purple-300 font-medium  text-white text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center  dark:bg-purple-300 dark:hover:bg-purple-600 dark:focus:bg-purple-900"
                >
                  Go to Website
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
        </div>
      </section>
     <TabSection />

     
    </main>
  );
}
```

not able to add get static props to re-render data in app routing.I have tried going through the docs as well,not much information available online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch data server-side in the app directory of Next.js? Tried getStaticProps but it's returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267351/how-to-fetch-data-server-side-in-the-app-directory-of-next-js-tried-getstaticpr)

Comment: i am fetching data usign axios by calling the api function from other file unlike the fetch method used here,also it does not explain anything about how it is rendering data.
Not able to get how i can render data in my case from the suggested link.