# Why the static site rendring isn`t working in nextJS 13.4.7?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, static-site-generation

## This is my code in nextJS, why nextjs don`t rerender the component Home twice. Cause at first render props in component Home is undefined

```
'use client'
import Layout from '@/components/layout/Layout'
import MeetupList from '@/components/meetups/MeetupList'

const DUMMY_MEETUPS = [
  {
    id:'m1',
    image:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS75ebrwvgVW5Ks_oLfCbG8Httf3_9g-Ynl_Q&usqp=CAU',
    title: 'Title',
    address: 'New York Green Street 21/3',
    description: 'Veniam veniam ex irure culpa. Proident est culpa anim deserunt. Voluptate do sit sint sint quis ea laboris dolor ex consequat laborum velit nostrud veniam.'
  },
  {
    id:'m2',
    image:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS75ebrwvgVW5Ks_oLfCbG8Httf3_9g-Ynl_Q&usqp=CAU',
    title: 'Title',
    address: 'New York Green Street 21/3',
    description: 'Veniam veniam ex irure culpa. Proident est culpa anim deserunt. Voluptate do sit sint sint quis ea laboris dolor ex consequat laborum velit nostrud veniam.'

  },
  {
    id:'m3',
    image:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS75ebrwvgVW5Ks_oLfCbG8Httf3_9g-Ynl_Q&usqp=CAU',
    title: 'Title',
    address: 'New York Green Street 21/3',
    description: 'Veniam veniam ex irure culpa. Proident est culpa anim deserunt. Voluptate do sit sint sint quis ea laboris dolor ex consequat laborum velit nostrud veniam.'

  }
];

export default function HomePage({meetups}) {
  console.log(meetups);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <MeetupList meetups={meetups}/>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  //fetch data from an API
  return {
    props: {
      meetups: DUMMY_MEETUPS,
    }
  };
}
```

## I expect from this code to assign value to props and make ssg(static side generation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch data server-side in the app directory of Next.js? Tried getStaticProps but it's returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267351/how-to-fetch-data-server-side-in-the-app-directory-of-next-js-tried-getstaticpr)