# getServerSideProps() in Next.js (using the App Router)

Tags: next.js

I have tried to touch Next.js 13 (using the App Router) and faced some issues. The structure of my test app is:

```
---/school
------/app
   ------/layout.tsx
   ------/page.tsx
---/src
```

The **./app/page.tsx** is

```
async function Page() {

    const hotels = await hotelService.getAllHotels()

    return (
        <RootLayout>
            <HomePage hotels={hotels}/>
        </RootLayout>
    )
}

export default Page
```

When **next build** makes **collecting page data** step the **hotelService.getAllHotels()** requests data from API by URL address. The URL address is defined by **$API_BACKEND_ENV** variable and depends on the environment (URL_FRO_DEV=https://1.1.1.1/hotel/all and URL_FRO_PROD=https://2.2.2.2/hotel/all).

The error comes from **const res = await fetch(this.url + "/hotel/all", { cache: 'no-store' })** line. If **this.url** not defined the error is thrown.

How can I avoid the **collecting page data** and throwing an exception?

NEXT JS [docs says](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) the **getServerSideProps()** is not launched the **next build** command. I tried to define **hotelService.getAllHotels()** inside the **getServerSideProps()** and expected not request the API. But it does not work.

```
async function Page({ data }) {

    return (
        <RootLayout>
            <HomePage hotels={data}/>
        </RootLayout>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const data = await hotelService.getAllHotels()  <<< I expect that this line is not launched while the <next build> command
    return {
        props: data
    }
}

export default Page
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want a behavior similar to `getServerSideProps` that does not run at build time, use the [`dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic) route config, like so:

```js
// layout.js / page.js / route.js

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"; //  

async function Page() {
  const hotels = await hotelService.getAllHotels();

  return (
    <RootLayout>
      <HomePage hotels={hotels} />
    </RootLayout>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

As a side note, [`getServerSideProps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76272755/15288641) itself won't work inside the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router (directory). Also, route segments only work in `layout`, `page`, and `route` files, not with normal components (like `getServerSideProps` didn't).