# My Next.js app keeps on telling me that my map function is not a function

Tags: next.js

I am creating a Next.js application that fetches data from an api concerning star wars films. It is meant to display the names of the films in a list and when you click on the title it takes you to another page which tells you more about the film you selected. I have tried to implement the fetch request to atleast display the title of the films but it keeps on telling me that my .map is not a function. The link to the api I am using is: https://swapi.dev

```
index.js
import Link from "next/link";
//install the isomorphic-unfetch
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Index = (props) => (
    <div>
    <h1>Star Wars Movies</h1>
    <ul>
        {props.films.map(({film}) => (
            <li key={film.id}>
                <Link as={`/p/${film.id}`} href={`/post?${film.id}`}>
                    <a>{film.title}</a>
                </Link>
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
    </div>
)

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
    const res = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/films')
    const data = await res.json()

    console.log(`Show data fetched. Count: ${data.length}`)

    return {
        films: data
    }
}

export default Index

post.js
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

const Post = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{props.film.title}</h1>
    <p>{props.film.opening_crawl.replace(/<[/]?p>/g, "")}</p>
  </div>
);

Post.getInitialProps = async function (context) {
    const { id } = context.query
    const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/films/${id}`)
    const film = await res.json()

    console.log(`Fetched film: ${film.title}`)

    return { film }
  }

  export default Post
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch data server-side in the latest Next.js? Tried getStaticProps but it's not running and getting undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267351/how-to-fetch-data-server-side-in-the-latest-next-js-tried-getstaticprops-but-it)