# Next.js - Create public API using params and Prisma for database

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I have a question, how to use Prisma on a page (ex api/blog/[id]/[slug2]).

I tested what Prisma offers with Next.js on their site, but I get this as an error:

Prisma doc used: https://www.prisma.io/nextjs#nextjs-tabs

```
Error: 
  x "getStaticProps" is not supported in app/. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching
  | 
  | 
    ,-[/vercel/path0/src/app/api/blog/[id]/[slug2]/page.tsx:10:1]
```

My code currently :

```
"use client"

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

type Props = {
  params: {
    id: string
    slug2: boolean
  }
  blogsLists: []
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  const blogsLists = await prisma.blogsList.findMany()

  return {
    props: { blogsLists },
  }
}

export default function BlogData({ params, blogsLists }: Props) {
  return (
    <p>
      Test : {params.id}/{params.slug2}
      {blogsLists.map((bloginfo) => (
        <li key={bloginfo}>{bloginfo.id}</li>
      ))}
    </p>
  )
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267351/how-to-fetch-data-server-side-in-the-latest-next-js-tried-getstaticprops-but-it
Check this out